# Dropping support for IE6, Is swfObject still relevant?

Tags: flash, embed, swfobject

We have recently dropped support for IE6 at my job. The other developers have have opted for a generic object embed method:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="example.swf" width="800" height="600" > 
      <param name="movie" value="example.swf"> 
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
</object>
```

This seems to work in all modern browsers but it really rubs me the wrong way. I'm sure this is wrong in several ways and is clearly a big step back in sophistication. So my question is in 2 parts, what is wrong with the above method? Is swfObject still best practice and what issues does it solve (besides IE6 click-activate)? Citations less then a year old would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes, SWFObject is still relevant.

SWFObject outputs `<object>` elements optimized for IE and for non-IE browsers. (IE 7 & 8 require a different setup than Firefox/Safari/Opera, most notably the *data* and *classid* attributes.)

I recommend SWFObject's *static publishing* method, which validates with the W3C and doesn't require JavaScript (the JS library is an add-on for extras, like Flash Player version detection). Static publishing uses a nested `<object>` to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

Learn more at http://learnswfobject.com

PS: "Click to activate" was [removed from Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2007/11/08/ie-automatic-component-activation-changes-to-ie-activex-update.aspx) in 2007.

Answer (score 0):

object with data is w3c compliant 
http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html

Comment: Standards is not the only consideration. I'm skeptical that this is cross browser.